# Regarding Operator Overloading for a Fraction Calculator

Tags: c++, pointers, this, overloading, operator-keyword

Part of my assignment is to use my professor's .cpp file. In it, I should be able to handle A = A + B where A and B are two fractions.

```
&Fraction Fraction::operator+(Fraction b)
{
  num = (num * b.denom) + (num * denom);/////// 
  denom = (denom * b.denom);
  if ((num * denom) >= 0) 
{ 
  sign_factor = 1;
}
else
{
  sign_factor = -1;
}
num = sign_factor * abs(num);
denom = sign_factor * abs(denom);
num = (num / (static_cast<double>(find_gcd(num, denom))));
denom = (denom / (static_cast<double>(find_gcd(num, denom))));
return this;
}
```

My question is how I would return the object A so that main.cpp can perform member assignment (assigning the result of A+B to A). Also, is it correct that I referred to num inside this function, or should I use a.num. For example, should it be "a.num = sign_factor  * abs(num) or is what I have okay?

Thankyou very much!!

Comment: `operator+` should not return a reference, but a new object. You need `Fraction operator+(Fraction b) const;`. Create a new `Fraction` in the body and return it.

Comment: mhmmm thats a great suggestion. ty

Comment: See [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) (although I disagree with some of the implementation details therein).

Comment: Would Marco's idea also work?

Comment: It depends what you mean by work. `A + B` should not modify `A`, so I would say it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @KevinCheng: Yes, but change this to `operator+=`. Then you can write `+` as a non-member `Fraction operator+(Fraction x, Fraction const & y) {return x += y;}`

Comment: Oh, in my Professor's main.cpp the code reads: A = A + B. Why shouldn't it modify A? Sorry for the questions! I appreciate your help :P Slow learner here

Comment: @KevinCheng: `A = whatever` should modify `A`; it's `A + B` that shouldn't.

Comment: Wait, @MikeSeymour, I can't modify my professor's main.cpp. Does this mean there is no point in doing so, or am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: @KevinCheng: There should be no need to change the professor's `A = A + B`. I'm saying that you should implement `operator+` so that it doesn't modify its operands. That is, for example, `C = A + B` should change `C`, but not `A`. With your implementation, it would also change `A`.

Comment: I think I understand you @MikeSeymour. If i did it my way, would I still get the intended results? Are you telling me to do it your way for formality reasons or because of actual output results? Thanks

Comment: @KevinCheng: You'd get the intended results; but also a surprising side-effect when `C = A+B` modifies `A`. This will lead to bugs if people (reasonably) expect `+` to give a new value, leaving its arguments unchanged, as the built-in operator does.

Answer (score 0):

This signature makes no sense:

```
&Fraction Fraction::operator+(Fraction b)
```

I don't know the purpose of your code but in `a = a + b` it might make sense to create a temporary with the result and return it

```
class Fraction {
public:
    Fraction operator+(Fraction b) const // Return a Fraction object
    {
        Fraction result;
        // ... initialize result...
        return result;
    }
};
```

if `num` is defined as a member variable of your `Fraction` class (or one of its subclasses) you can safely use it as you did or as `this->num`

---

Edit:

In regard to your comment, I'm adding some code to explain why returning a temporary object might make more sense. Compare the two versions and decide which one suits your needs better. Intuitively the first one is the preferred and most logical choice.

- Version 1: returning a temporary (`a` doesn't get modified)

  ```
  class Fraction {
  public:

      Fraction operator+(Fraction& b)
      {
          Fraction result;
          result.num = num + b.num;

          return result;
      }

      void operator=(Fraction& b)
      {
          num = b.num;
      }

      int num;
  };


  int main()
  {

      Fraction a, b, c;
      a.num = 10;
      b.num = 20;
      c.num = 0;

      c = a + b;
      // a is now 10
      // b is now 20
      // c is now 30
  }
  ```
- Version 2: returning a reference and modifying `a`

  ```
  class Fraction {
  public:

      Fraction& operator+(Fraction& b)
      {
          num = num + b.num;

          return *this;
      }

      void operator=(Fraction& b)
      {
          num = b.num;
      }

      int num;
  };


  int main()
  {

      Fraction a, b, c;
      a.num = 10;
      b.num = 20;
      c.num = 0;

      c = a + b;
      // a is now 30 <- I believe you don't want this
      // b is now 20
      // c is now 30
  }
  ```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: Thanks! This won't return a dangling reference correct? Because a and B will still be defined in main and won't go out of scope until the terminating brace in main?

Comment: Although returning a reference from `operator+` doesn't make much sense either. Unless it does something other than addition, it needs to return a new object, leaving its operands unchanged. This is more like `operator+=`.

Comment: I ignore the purpose of his code but I suppose a temporary might make sense here

Comment: @KevinCheng I took a second look and it makes sense to create a temporary value, initialize it with the results of `a + b` and then return it. `a + b` isn't necessarily `a` unless you meant to mimic `operator+=` behavior as Mike wrote.

Comment: Can you please explain why a+b isn't necessarily a? I dont understand.

Comment: @KevinCheng Edited the post, take a look at which behavior you want to implement and pay attention to `a` being modified or not